# tkinter - How to fix label and check button not lining up?

Tags: python, tkinter

Below is a part of a code which opens a file and creates a label and check button for every person on the register but when I run the code, the label and check buttons aren't aligned and I don't know why. Can someone help?

[image: screenshot of current results]

Code:

```
x=0
for line in open(register, "r"):
    with open(register,"r") as file:
        all_lines=file.readlines()
    Label(registersuccess,text=all_lines[x]).grid(column=0,row=x)
    Checkbutton(registersuccess,text="Present").grid(column=1,row=x)
    x=x+1
```

Comment: What have you tried? `grid` has many options. Have you experimented with them?

Comment: ive tried with changing the sticky and pads but the doesnt seem to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**:  `Label` text and `Checkbutton` text does not lining up?

Your problem are the new lines `\n`. By reading from a text file, every line ends with `\n`. Therefore your `text = line` becomes `text='Boy1\n'` which is **two lines** and does not lining up with the `Checkbutton` text which is **one line**.
**Result after removed, the `\n` using `.strip()`**:  [image]

---

**Reference**:

- [str.strip([chars])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

  > Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed,  the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace.
- [str.rstrip([chars])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip)

  > Return a copy of the string with trailing characters removed, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace
- [enumerate(iterable, start=0)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

  > Returns a tuple containing a count and the values obtained from iterating over iterable.
- [7.2. Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

  > It is good practice to use the with keyword when dealing with file objects. The advantage is that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes.

---

```
import tkinter as tk
import io

# Simulate the contents of the file 'register'
register = """Boy 1
Girl 1
Boy 2
Girl 2
Boy 3
Girl 3
"""


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # with open(register) as fh:
        with io.StringIO(register) as fh:
            for row, line in enumerate(fh):
                text = line.strip()
                
                tk.Label(self, text=text).grid(row=row, column=0)
                tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Present").grid(row=row, column=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - 'TclVersion': 8.6 'TkVersion': 8.6***

Answer (score 1):

The alignment problem is because the lines in file all end with a newline character, which you can remove by using the string `rstrip()` method. You're also doing things very inefficiently since you reading the entire file in each time through the inner-most `for` loop.

Here's how to avoid that as well as fix the problem:

```
from tkinter import *

register = 'register.txt'
root = Tk()
registersuccess = Frame(root)
registersuccess.pack()

with open(register, "r") as file:
    for row, line in enumerate(file):
        line = line.rstrip()  # Remove trailing newline.
        Label(registersuccess, text=line).grid(column=0, row=row)
        Checkbutton(registersuccess, text='Present').grid(column=1, row=row)

Button(registersuccess, text='Submit').grid(column=2, row=row+1)

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image: screenshot of result]